# Error while Plotting Decision Boundary using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I recently wrote a Logistic regression model using Scikit Module. However, I'm having a REALLY HARD time plotting the decision boundary line. I'm explicitly multiplying the Coefficients and the Intercepts and plotting them (which in turn throws a wrong figure).

Could someone point me in the right direction on how to plot the decision boundary?

Is there an easier way to plot the line without having to manually multiply the coefficients and the intercepts?

Thanks a Million!

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

#Import Dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv("Students Exam Dataset.txt", names=["Exam 1", "Exam 2", "Admitted"])
print(dataset.head())

#Visualizing Dataset
positive = dataset[dataset["Admitted"] == 1]
negative = dataset[dataset["Admitted"] == 0]

plt.scatter(positive["Exam 1"], positive["Exam 2"], color="blue", marker="o", label="Admitted")
plt.scatter(negative["Exam 1"], negative["Exam 2"], color="red", marker="x", label="Not Admitted")
plt.title("Student Admission Plot")
plt.xlabel("Exam 1")
plt.ylabel("Exam 2")
plt.legend()
plt.plot()
plt.show()

#Preprocessing Data
col = len(dataset.columns)
x = dataset.iloc[:,0:col].values
y = dataset.iloc[:,col-1:col].values
print(f"X Shape: {x.shape}   Y Shape: {y.shape}")

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1306)

#Initialize Model
reg = LogisticRegression()
reg.fit(x_train, y_train)

#Output
predictions = reg.predict(x_test)
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions) * 100
coeff = reg.coef_
intercept = reg.intercept_
print(f"Accuracy Score : {accuracy} %")
print(f"Coefficients = {coeff}")
print(f"Intercept Coefficient = {intercept}")

#Visualizing Output
xx = np.linspace(30,100,100)
decision_boundary = (coeff[0,0] * xx + intercept.item()) / coeff[0,1]
plt.scatter(positive["Exam 1"], positive["Exam 2"], color="blue", marker="o", label="Admitted")
plt.scatter(negative["Exam 1"], negative["Exam 2"], color="red", marker="x", label="Not Admitted")
plt.plot(xx, decision_boundary, color="green", label="Decision Boundary")
plt.title("Student Admission Plot")
plt.xlabel("Exam 1")
plt.ylabel("Exam 2")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Dataset: [Student Dataset.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19hQ05F12fUb7gwHLccNWDgpHKCGAGo5p/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an easier way to plot the line without having to manually multiply the coefficients and the intercepts?

Yes, if you don't need to build this from scratch, there is an excellent implementation of plotting decision boundaries from scikit-learn classifiers in the [`mlxtend`](http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/plotting/plot_decision_regions/) package. The documentation is extensive in the link provided and it's easy to install with `pip install mlxtend`.

First, a couple points about the `Preprocessing` block of the code you posted:
 1. `x` should not include the class labels.
 2. `y` should be a `1d` array.

```
#Preprocessing Data
col = len(dataset.columns)
x = dataset.iloc[:,0:col-1].values # assumes your labels are always in the final column.
y = dataset.iloc[:,col-1:col].values
y = y.reshape(-1) # convert to 1d
```

Now the plotting is as easy as:

```
from mlxtend.plotting import plot_decision_regions
plot_decision_regions(x, y,
                      X_highlight=x_test,
                      clf=reg,
                      legend=2)
```

This particular plot highlights `x_test` data points by encircling them.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a Million! Just for personal info, can the same be achieved using matplotlib or scikit having the same order of simplicity?

Comment: Examples from the scikit-learn docs: [DecisionTree](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_iris.html) and [SVM](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_iris.html). [Nice examples from a Kaggle kernel](https://www.kaggle.com/arthurtok/decision-boundaries-visualised-via-python-plotly) It's certainly more lines of code than using the `mlxtend` method, but up to you

Comment: I've recently started to face this issue where I get an error saying "ValueError: Filler values must be provided when X has more than 2 training features." Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: See `Example 7` from the mlxtend link. When there are more than two features, it requires "filler" values for the features not being plotted.  The links in my previous comment are more straightforward examples. You can always slice the columns from `x` that you want. For example the first and second feature:  `x[:, 0]` and `x[:, 1]`.